# 'brew' command is not recognized by Terminal

Tags: homebrew

I have installed `brew` on my system using the command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Now, it seems that it was successfully installed. But when I type `brew` in Terminal, I get:

```
zsh: command not found: brew
```

Honestly, I do not know what `zsh` means. Some people say to just add some line to a certain file (I assume it is a configuration file for `zsh`). I think the file is `~/.zshrc`, however, there is no such file on my system. How do I access it? Should I type `vim ~/.zshrc` in Terminal? How do I make my system recognize `brew` and all the other programs I would like to install?

I typed `vim ~/ .zshrc` in Terminal which opened `vim`. I then typed "i" in order to edit the file but I get `please type the directory name:`. I wonder what should I type here?

Comment: RE: "I typed `vim ~/ .zshrc` in Terminal which opened `vim`." -- You have a _space_ between `vim ~/` and `.zshrc`, you need to remove the _space_. Type: `vim ~/.zshrc`

Comment: For some reason the Brew command is not on your execution path or the install has stuffed up in some way. Re-run the installation script and paste the output on this question so we can see what's going on. You could also try providing a full path e.g. type "/usr/local/bin/brew help" to see if it's installed.

Comment: This sounds like you have an M1 machine. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

When installing brew on my new Macbook where I immediately added ZSH i ran into the same problem but If you look carefully at your installation you might see:

```
Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
  Instructions on how to configure your shell for Homebrew
  can be found in the 'Next steps' section below.
```

and below you should see something like:

```
==> Next steps:
- Run these three commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
    echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/****/.zprofile
    echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/****/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

after running those commands I could run brew. Hopefully this helps someone

Comment: I put this in my .bashrc in my m2 and it fixed the problem, thanks!